# LIKE in multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have columns `title`, `description`, `keywords` and I want to search a text in them.
I'm using PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT title FROM products
WHERE
     ANY(ARRAY(title, description, keywords) like '%test%')
```

I'm getting error `syntax error at or near "ANY"`.
I know I can do it with `OR` but I think that would not be the best way to do it.

I think I'm having errors at converting columns to array. Can someone give me an idea?
Thanks!

Comment: `OR` seems like the best approach to me.  I cannot think of any particular elegance in moving columns into arrays, just to pull them apart for `LIKE`.

Comment: `ANY` is the same as `IN`, so you can't use wildcards there, you can use it for equal like `WHERE ('Foo' = ANY (ARRAY[title, description, keywords])) IS TRUE;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, your goal is to only have the comparison `'%test%'` appear once.  Here is one method:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[p.title, p.description, p.keywords]) x
              WHERE x LIKE '%test%'
             )
```

Note that if you using equality, then `IN` suffices:

```
WHERE test IN (p.title, p.description, p.keywords)
```

Comment: Thanks, which one do you think would give better performance? I have no problem with using `'%test%'` multiple times but that just feels wrong for performance.

Comment: @sh4dowb . . . They are going to be pretty similar.  Both will require full table scans.  It is hard to avoid that without a full text index.